# Export a model from Blender to Cryengine

Tags: export, blend-files

How can I export a model from Blender to Cryengine?

I have tried using CryBlend also, but that does not work either.

Comment: What formats can CryEngine import?

Comment: Why does CryBlend not work? If there are any issues with the addon, you should contact the author (it's not an officially maintained addon AFAIK).